# Can't initiliaze an internal hard drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I decided to do a clean install of windows. During the setup, i noticed 5 or 6 "system partitions" on my disk 0, so I deleted them all, along with the main partitions where Windows was installed. After the installation, one of my thee hard drives failed to show up. Under disk management, I see that it's "Not Intialized", and Windows is offering to initialize it for me.

When I select GPT, I get the following error

```
The specific disk is not convertible because the size is less 
than the minimum size required for GPT disks.
```

When I try MBR, I get the following error

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I get the same error when I try to do this operation with `DISKPART`

Also, this drive shows up in Device Manager as an "unknown device".

Comment: How many disks do you physically have?

Comment: @Appleoddity, 3 physical drives. The OS is installed on a 256GB SSH (Disk 0), and then I have a 5TB drive (Disk 1) and a 2TB drive (Disk 2). The 5TB Disk 1 the one that I can't access